# How to make two controllers perform same action in Angular, but change visual aspect of site?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application

I would like to replicate Google's home page functionality in Angular, and it's causing me grief. I've gone through the Egghead videos and read the entire API, but there's no particular example for that exact behavior. What I'd like it to do is the following:

- user comes to home page, main search bar is present and generic black header bar
- user searches for something, and only when he presses "search" does the main search bar disappear, the url changes to mysite.com/q/searchTerm and a new sub-header appears under the black header bar much like with Google's home page, where the main search field is removed and placed in a grayish bar under the main header bar (if you have instant-search off)
- the results of the search appear in place of the now gone main search bar, just like with Google, but this part I can handle with routes and views. The layout switch between two identical controllers is what bothers me.

So far what I've tried was:

- make a parent controller for both MainCtrl sub controllers, and set its scope.data = {searchHeaderDisplay: false}
- have both sub controllers share the same name (MainCtrl) because they share the exact same functionality
- make the one in the header bar ng-show="data.searchHeaderDisplay" and the main one ng-hide="data.searchHeaderDisplay" and then try switching the data.searchHeaderDisplay on ng-click of Search Button. This didn't work - no effect was produced.

I'm still coming to terms with AngularJS, so I'm sure it's quite simple, I just need a practical example or two to learn from.

Edit: would it be better to shove the secondary header (with the smaller search field) into a separate view template along with the search results, and just have the root view be the main search field? The documentation is very lax on best practices regarding views and routes, especially routes that will have multiple controllers doing something.

Comment: Like you, I had been looking (still am, sometimes) for best practices in applying AngularJS for various common scenarios. The truth is best practices are merely in the process of hatching at best, because AngularJS is still very new in the world of web development, in terms its philosophy and approaches. One thing I have learned over the course of learning and using AngularJS is don't spend time on looking for best practices, as they don't exist, but be experimental yourself and also learn from other developers' experience to come up with good approaches for your use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you set `scope.data = {searchHeaderDisplay: false}` on the parent controller of the two `MainCtrl` controllers, with the intention to enable the `MainCtrl` controllers to share the same model data. That's all fine.

Without seeing your code, my guess is that the problem lies in how you switch `data.searchHeaderDisplay` on ng-click. You might have set `data.searchHeaderDisplay` at the child scope level (ie. the scopes that corresponds the `MainCtrl` controllers) when you should have assign the value to their parent scope level. Let me know if you need me to elaborate.

**UPDATE:**

After taking a look of the provided code, the problem is indeed as what I suspected earlier (above).

`mainProductSearch()` is what needs to be changed. Instead of `scope.data.searchHeaderVisible = true;`, you need `scope.$parent.data.searchHeaderVisible = true` for the reason briefly explained earlier. If the rationale behind is still not clear to you, then you probably need to familiarize yourself with **prototypal inheritance chain of AngularJS scope (and/or Javascript object in general)**. Scope prototypal inheritance an essential part of AngularJS. [Here is a great article on the topic](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance).

Comment: Thank you. Here's my code, in a nutshell. It won't work because it depends on my local server since it's just been copied to jsfiddle directly, but hopefully you can glean something from it: http://jsfiddle.net/e7nBt/ what's curious is that even if I define data.searchHeaderVisible like in the JS part, the MainCtrls act the opposite - the one with show is hidden and the one with hide is shown initially. I do the switch in mainProductSearch function, but nothing happens.

Comment: also briefly edited main question on if I should perhaps change it all to routes and views and avoid all this

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an AppCtrl (which is essentially acting like $rootScope), and using `$parent` (which is a fragile solution because changing the HTML structure could cause this to break -- e.g., you might find you need to use `$parent.$parent...` if you add an intermediate ng-controller), I suggest a service for storing model data related to your header.  Let's call it `searchService`.

Controllers that need to affect this model can inject the service.  This has the additional advantage that the dependencies are clear (vs controller $scope inheritance, where the dependencies are not clear).  E.g., when the user presses "search", the controller can call a notification method defined on the service:  `searchService.newSearchTerm(searchTerm)`.  Now, all views (like the header view) that are watching for changes in the model will notice the change and can update accordingly.

You might consider using ng-view for the main content area of your page.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14619122/215945, where a very similar layout is discussed.  In that SO post, a shopping basket with an item count is in the header.  The item count needed to be updated by multiple controllers, so we put it into a service.

Comment: @Swader - My solution is for making your code to work. But if we take a step backward and look at the design, Mark's solution is no doubt a better one because it's more modularized and thus more flexible to work with in the long run.

Comment: @tamakisquare I just changed it to Mark's solution and it works like a charm. Your answer helped answer the original question at hand, though, so it stays marked as accepted.

Comment: @Mark thank you, this worked great. I've learned a lot through this refactoring process and even delved into Angular's and AngularUI's source, too, finding out new and curious features and bugs.